# Dynamically update lightning-combobox lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to dynamically update option in a lightning-combobox standard component.
I passed to the component a list of option which is annotated with the @track decorator but the combobox won't update when I push new options in this list.

Template :

```html
    <lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            label="Type"
            value={selectedType}
            options={selectOptions}
            onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

Controller :

```js
import {LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';

export default class TsrWhat extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getList, {recordType: 'Timesheet_Report_What'})
    lists({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            for(const list of data){
                const option = {
                    label: list.Name,
                    value: list.Data_Store__c
                };
                this.selectOptions.push(option);
            }
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    @track
    selectOptions = [
        {label: "All the business actvities", value: "All BA"},
        {label: "List of all the business actvities", value: "ListRoot"}
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In LWC, generally it is not allowed to modify the existing memory location. `push` will modify existing memory location. This is how all modern libraries like `Reactjs` works. So, you can create new memory location using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as below:

```
@wire(getList, {recordType: 'Timesheet_Report_What'})
lists({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        for(const list of data){
            const option = {
                label: list.Name,
                value: list.Data_Store__c
            };
            // this.selectOptions.push(option);
            this.selectOptions = [ ...this.selectOptions, option ];
        }
    } else if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an off-topic question:  I really appreciate all your time and efforts in providing valuables answers to our community. How you tend to keep up with the ever-changing LWC concepts? Can you share some ideas on how to learn these concepts and keep up? My project assignments doesn't have any of this applications, so I am willing to learn on my own. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You can follow 3 main sources. [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc) and [Releases](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_feature_impact.htm?edition=&impact=). Its a lot of information - just take it step by step - everyday - learn a little. :)