# How to show the field value of records from a Custom object as a picklist values in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to show the values from one of the field from multiple records of a custom object as picklist values for the lightning-combobox input field in LWC ?

Scenario:
Note - I want to make the below scenario as dynamic because I will be fetching the record's value from a custom object.

```
Custom Object
Record1 - Name - John
Record2 - Name - David
Record3 - Name - Leonardo
```

LWC

```
<lightning-combobox options={values} label="Contacts"/>
```

JS

```
get values{
  return [
    {label:'John', value:'John'},
    {label:'David', value:'David'},
    {label:'Leonardo', value:'Leonardo'}
];
}
```

Comment: Please try to do some search. There are several documents provided by Salesforce. If you are facing any technical difficulty then post it here.

Comment: Obviously I did some research before posting here. Can you answer only then I can say if you understand my question or not ? Okay

Comment: What happened ? Answer please @SalesforceDevelopment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#JS#

`           import { LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc';
**//import apex method**

```
    export default class Sample extends LightningElement {
    @track items = []; //this will hold key, value pair
    @track value = ''; //initialize combo box value
    @track chosenValue = '';

    @wire(getRecords)
     wiredRecords({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {

        //create array with elements which has been retrieved controller
        //here value will be record Id and label of combobox will be Name of record
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
            this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ];                                   
        }                
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        
    }
}

get recordOptions() {
    return this.items;
}

              handleChange(event) {
         // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option
        const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
    console.log('selected value=' + selectedOption);
    this.chosenValue = selectedOption;
}

//this value will be shown as selected value of combobox item
get selectedValue(){
    return this.chosenValue;
}
```

}`

///****************HTML*********************////

```
      <lightning-combobox
        name="My Records"
        label="MY Records"
        value={value}
        onchange={handleChange}
        options={recordOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>
```

///********Apex Controller*****************//

```
public with sharing class RecordController{

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<CustomObj__c> getRecords(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObj__c];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

It is called **lightning-combobox**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example

you can make dynamic values for options in the controller

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            label="Status"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Select Progress"
            options={options}
            onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

    <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>



import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    value = 'inProgress';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275530/dynamically-update-lightning-combobox-lightning-web-component